# Can't add user to group without a restart?

Tags: linux, users, group

I'm trying to add a user to a group `wireshark` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458762/how-to-enable-wireshark-without-running-as-root-in-trusty-14-04).

I have already executed multiple different commands and was under the impression that the user was successfully added.

```
~$ sudo adduser $USER wireshark
The user `user' is already a member of `wireshark'.
```

And have re logged into the system.

```
~$ groups 
user adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

but it seems as if the user hasn't been added to the group (which is in contrast with the first command). Also the assumption that it wasn't added is supported by Wireshark not working correctly.

Which should I consider correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It starter to show the appropriate groups only after a system restart. The logout - login wasn't enough.

Don't know what to make of it.

Comment: I encountered the same when working with an Amazon EC2 instance running their own flavor of "Amazon Linux". I had to restart the instance for the group change to take effect. Exiting and starting a new terminal session was not enough.

Comment: same here: I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and only after a restart I could see the new group membership ... very rare ...

Answer (score 7):

The command `groups` is not showing you as a member of wireshark and you're unable to use wireshark properly unprivileged. Chances are something has not worked with the `adduser` wrapper script.

What works for me when enabling new users to use wireshark is the following.

```
$ sudo usermod -aG wireshark $USER
```

Then log the user out and back in. You should now be able to use wireshark as a non root user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `ControlMaster` in your `$HOME/.ssh/conf` file, logging out and logging back in won't work (as you didn't really log out). Execute

```
ssh -O exit <ssh nickname>
```

to force close all open connections, then log in again.

Comment: Maybe you could expand your answer and describe how exactly this fixes the issue that user doesn't get added to wireshark -group until system is restarted?